# position is not a valid member of Part?

Tags: exception, lua, position, roblox

i have the code below, it should be working as coping a part called "boulder"(unanchored), and moving it to the desired position, but instead:"position is not a valid member of Part"

```
while true do
    wait(2)
    local original = workspace.boulder
    -- Create the model copy
    local copy = original:Clone()
    -- Parent the copy to the same parent as the original
    copy.Parent = original.Parent
    -- Move the copy so it's not overlapping the original
    copy.position = CFrame.new(-84.76, 206.227, 143.094) -- where error happens
    Debris:AddItem(copy, 2)
end
```

Comment: its `Position` with capital P. Please refer to manuals or at least search the web for "roblox part position" befor you post a question here. thanks. https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/property/BasePart/Position

Comment: ok, i will try with that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you seem to be having is because `Position` is supposed to have a capital P.

Fix:

```
while true do
wait(2)
local original = workspace.boulder
-- Create the model copy
local copy = original:Clone()
-- Parent the copy to the same parent as the original
copy.Parent = original.Parent
-- Move the copy so it's not overlapping the original
copy.Position = CFrame.new(-84.76, 206.227, 143.094) -- Position Capitalised correctly
Debris:AddItem(copy, 2)
```

end

Comment: Oops, didn't realise that this was already answered in the comments, I'll leave this answer up to allow for this question to show as answered and make it obvious that there is indeed an answer